# Memory allocation for objects in R

Tags: r

I am trying to understand the memory allocation in R.
So I populated 2 methods with same results. So Does this mean method with lesser allocation is efficient

For example

```
## Method 1
f <- function(num) {
  for(i in seq_len(num)) {
    cat("Hello, world!\n") }}

object.size(f(1))
Hello, world!
  0 bytes

## Method 2
asd <- "Hello, world!"
object.size(asd)
120 bytes
```

So if you see above, Method 1 is more efficient than Method 1 right?  (0 and 120 bytes respectively)

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not comparing like with like. Your function prints `"Hello, world!"` but returns nothing. Therefore when you run `object.size(f(1))`, you are essentially running `object.size(NULL)`, which is 0 (the size of nothing).

If you change your function so that it returns a string, it would be equivalent to Method 2 (assigning a value to a string):

```r
f <- function(num) {
    for (i in seq_len(num)) {
        return("Hello, world!\n")
    }
}

object.size(f(1)) # 120 bytes
object.size(f(1)) == object.size("Hello, world!") # TRUE
```

In either case you are measuring the size of the string. However, simply allocating the string in this case is going to use less RAM, as the function itself takes up space in memory:

```
object.size(f) # 16088 bytes
```

Even an empty function in R will take up about 4k of RAM:

```r
g  <- function() {
    return(TRUE)
}
object.size(g) # 4384 bytes
```

Having said this, given that in R you are generally working with data held in RAM, the amount of overhead storing functions is usually negligible by comparison. Most of the time in R you will want to optimise for clarity of your code (i.e. use functions), rather than small amounts of RAM. There are exceptions though (e.g. calling a function millions of times in a loop).

Comment: One question. Since you mentioned that even empty function consumes RAM, so should we avoid using functions in shiny applications ?

Comment: No. You should use functions in Shiny applications. On the client side, any Shiny app is going to be in a browser. Browsers are notorious for their RAM-hunger (e.g. Chrome right now is using 1.6GB of RAM on my system). On the server side, if you have so many users that you are worried about allocating a few kb of RAM for each one, you would be much better served looking at whether data can be stored out of memory and ultimately whether Shiny is the right framework. Basically, the amount of RAM functions use is tiny and you should use functions because it makes the code clearer.

Comment: Thanks. You mentioned "data can be stored out of memory". How is it possible? :)